# Prevent WebStorm auto import from other Angular project in the same workspace

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I have angular repository with two projects: one is a library and second is an Angular application.
I have used `npm link` to link library to my project. In `package.json` I have specified entry:

```
...
"my-lib": "~0.0.1"
...
```

I have also specified this `PageQuery` class in `public-api.ts`:

```
export * from './lib/table/models/paged-result';
```

When I want to use an exported element from the library in the app, WebStorm by default will do something like this:

```
import { PageQuery } from '../../../../../projects/my-lib/src/lib/page-query';
```

instead of this:

```
import { PageQuery } from 'my-lib';
```

**Notice**: Although it works when I type it as above manually, but I would like to inform WebStorm, that this should be the defeault import.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer myself. Looks like it didn't work in my previous version 2019.1. After upgrading to 2020.2 it gives the correct suggestion (the first one is the desired one):
[image]